# Reactjs error: babel-runtime.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I am brand new to reactjs, and I am using it in a meteor project I am trying to learn.
Here is the code to help =]:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends ReactDOM.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    )
  }
}

if(Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function(){
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("render-target"));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`react` and `react-dom` are different modules. It's the `react` module that has `Component` defined. So change to this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    )
  }
}

if(Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function(){
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("render-target"));
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jacob helped alot!